# Why aren't we using l'hospital's rule in this limit ? $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)}{e^x-e^{-x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

For this equation, $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)}{e^x-e^{-x}}$, I have found the solution:

We divide by $e^x$.

however, when you take into account that it's $\frac \infty \infty$, we should use l'hospital's rule but instead we're diving by $e^x$. Why didn't we use l'hospital's rule given that the equation is infinity/infinity ?

Comment: Attempt to use l'hospital's rule ... you end up right where you started

Comment: have you tried applying L'Hospital's rule? If not, try it and maybe you'll notice something

Comment: @jameselmore Not quite,  you get the reciprocal,  which does let us say that if the limit exists, it must be a number that  is its own multiplicative inverse....

Comment: You are never *forced* to use L'Hôpital's rule; it doesn't make sense to say you "should" use it. It is a tool that is often, but not always, helpful.

Comment: To the OP,  "can" use L'hospitals is different than "should" use L'hospitals.   This one is legal to use it for,  so it fits "can".   But doing so only lets you conclude that the limit must be 1 IF IT EXISTS,  so unless you can prove the limit exists some other way,  it doesn't help, thus you "shouldn't

Comment: @Alan It could also be $-1$.

Comment: @Théophile Doh! Okay, I need more caffeine.  And jinx on the forced/should part :)

Comment: Could someone please use l'hopital's rule, that would be pretty beneficial. I feel like this question hasn't been asked before

Comment: It has been asked before, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1574663/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4165886/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/912694/42969

Comment: Definitely ! Thanks

Comment: The answer to the question "has this been asked before?" is almost always yes, at least in my experience on this site : )

Comment: Now I can't ask any question :(